# Where can I find a list of English hyphenation exceptions?

Tags: hyphenation

I know that a nice list of (English) hyphenation exceptions was published in TUGboat, in quite a few installments.  Is it compiled somewhere in one place?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

whenever an update is published in tugboat, the complete "list-so-far"
is posted to ctan as a pdf file [tb0hyf.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/tb0hyf.pdf) and the tex source [tb0hyf.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/tb0hyf.tex).
the most recent update was in november 2010.

taking a cue from egreg, the entire package, `hyphenex`, is available from ctan and is also part of tex live.  the package includes the processing module and the preprocessed list,
[ushyphex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/ushyphex.tex), as well as the tugboat material.

**update:** suggestions for additions can be mailed to `tugboat@tug.org`

Comment: Where do we email suggestions for this list?

Comment: @MSC -- see update.

Comment: What about the new selnolig package?

Answer (score 12):

for US-english run

```
kpsewhich ushyphex.tex
```

for TeXLive => `$TEXMF/tex/generic/hyphenex/ushyphex.tex`

I don't know if there is also an exception log for GB english.

Comment: this isn't the most recent version.  tex live 2010 closed before the latest update; for that, you have to go to ctan.

Comment: @Barbara: true, but I have TeXLive 2011 installed :-)

Comment: @Herbert, I have copied the output of kpswehich ushyphex.tex in between the brackets of an `\input{}` in my preamble, would you say that is the 'correct' way of doing it?

Comment: you do not need the path a `\input{ushyphex.tex}` should be enough.

Answer (score 10):

The CTAN location is

http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/ushyphex.tex

Comment: it is part on _every_ TeX installation ...

Comment: @Herbert: is it also in MiKTeX minimal?

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I am not at all surprised that I have it somewhere in my texlive installation - but I did not know the filename...

Comment: @Stephen: A TeX distribution is MiKTeX or TeXLive

Comment: @Stephen I would argue with Herbert. IMHO if you say "In it a part of both TeX installations" then you really mean MiKTeX and TeXLive. But as you point out, there're other distros as well.

Comment: @Stephen: since `ushyphex.tex` is *only* in tex live, that i can tell, the only useful statement is "it's in tex live".  (note, i don't run an up-to-date miktex, so i'm going by the list of locations in miktex's `files.csv`.)

Comment: Since August 2023, it's in MiKTeX too. Source: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/388

Answer (score 0):

On MiKTeX, the path is `C:\MiKTeX\tex\generic\hyphenex\ushyphex.tex`, in case MiKTeX is installed at `C:\MiKTeX`. On CTAN, the package is [hyphenex](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyphenex), which contains [ushyphex.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/ushyphex.tex).

Additional information: I was interested in using the list. Following an example using luatex and [showhypens](https://ctan.org/pkg/showhyphens) to illustrate the new hyphenation. The package works with pdflatex, too.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showhyphens}
\begin{document}
\input{ushyphex}
antinuclear
\enddocument}
```

Note: One needs to update MiKTeX to [August 2023](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/388) (or later) to make use of the file.

[image: ani-nu-clear hyphenation]

Comment: Actually, "bare" TeX works as well if it's installed on your system.  At a command line prompt, type "tex <return>".  The next prompt will be `**`; type `\relax` <return>.  Then, type `\showhyphens{...}` with the  test word(s).  The words, with hyphens, will. be typed out on the monitor.  To end the session, type `\bye`, and the record of the session will be in the file `texput.log`.  (I maintain the exceptions list, and that's how I test.  The list *is* due for an update; I'm working toward publication in TUGboat 44:3 later this year.)