# The justified is going beyond the margins or even the page

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm tryng to make a small booklet with big letters them the number of carecteres in each line is small and latex isn't helping the matter because he don't stop at the margins sometimes eitheir in the page.What comand i should use to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do several things to help matters.  First, you can use the `microtype` package.  Second, you can help LaTeX figure out where to hyphenate words; see e.g. [another question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27890/how-to-add-global-hyphenation-rules)