# Doing Automation Hyphenation

Tags: margins, hyphenation

I want to make automation for hyphenation so I didn't need to write `tra- \gedy`

Is a package in latex that could help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt,A4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\section{Mathematical Modeling for the Probability of Queueing at Healthcare Facility Resources}
\end{document}
```

The sentence 'Mathematical Modeling for the Probability of Queueing at Healthcare Facility Resources' will be out of the margin.

[image: Out of the margin]

Comment: Chech [How to add global hyphenation rules?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27890/140133). It uses the package `hyphenat` and command `\hyphenation`.

Comment: do you really want to hyphenate a section heading? long titles are usually better set ragged right

Comment: @FHZ thank you so much, it's work!

Comment: I'm voting to close the question since it was solved as presented in a link given in the comments.