# LaTeX hyphens pattern file for medical terminology

Tags: hyphenation, ctan

This might be slightly off topic since my main goal is to hyphenate strings in Java, but please bare with me.

So far I've only looked at [TeXHyphenator-J](http://www.davidashen.net/texhyphj.html) and [Hyphenation](https://bitbucket.org/feuervogel/hyphenation) libraries and both of them use LaTeX hyphenation patterns.

I would like to hyphenate strings for US English, ideally taking into account medical terms which tend to be lengthy.

I've used multiple [US patterns found on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/hyphenation/ushyph) but notice the hypenation isn't quite correct.
For example, inputting a string like

> Deoxyribonucleic acid, sternocleidomastoid,
>   dicotiledoneas,Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis

I've got results like these:

> De-oxyri-bonu-cle-ic acid, ster-n-oclei-do-mas-toid,
>   di-cotile-doneas,P-neu-monoul-tra-mi-cro-scop-ic-sil-i-co-vol-canoco-nio-sis
>
> Deoxy-ri-bo-nucleic a-ci-d, s-tern-oclei-do-mas-to-i-d,
>   di-co-ti-le-do-ne-as,P-neu-mo-noul-tra-mi-cros-co-pic-si-li-co-vol-ca-no-co-nio-sis

Are there any LaTeX patterns for hyphenating medical terms in (US)English ?
If so, where can I find them ?

If not, is it possible to create such a pattern ? Where would I start ?

Comment: I think that making a file with hyphenation exceptions is better. I don't think there is anything like this, at the moment.

Comment: see the question [Where can I find a list of English hyphenation exceptions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22867/579) for information on how to add to the extant list of exceptions.

Comment: @egreg that's a nice little workaround, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to correctly hyphenate the medical idiom it sounds like preparing a new language. TeX uses [Liang's algorithm](http://tug.org/docs/liang/liang-thesis.pdf). Accordingly the hyphenation patterns are made for it. The TeX distributions contain a program `patgen` to generate the hyphenation pattern from a (large) list of correctly hyphenated words.

Comment: Great, I'll look into patgen and see if I can generate a pattern. Thanks(+1)