# Reliability of LaTeX hyphenation

Tags: languages, hyphenation, ieee-style

1. I'm not native English.
2. I have to write an academic paper with LaTeX, in US English, without mistakes.

My problem is with hyphenation. I do not know whether it is done correctly.

I use:

- MikTeX.
- `\hyphenation{mon-i-tor-ing sub-se-quently pro-vi-sion-ally
  Smart-Road-Sen-se}` for the words that I know that the hyphenation is
  wrong.
- LanguageTool `C:\Program
  Files\LanguageTool-2.8\languagetool.jar` (in TeXstudio).

**And now the question: there is a tool to control (and improve) hyphenation in LaTeX, without looking at all the words in the PDF?**

Comment: You really have `SmartRoadSense` as a single word?

Comment: The default hyphenations on those words are `mon-i-tor-ing sub-se-quently pro-vi-sion-ally SmartRoad-Sense` so you need nothing except for the “nonstandard word”. Can you show an example where `monitoring` (or another word in the list) is hyphenated incorrectly?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Of course: this is the my main project. :-)

Comment: as egreg says the other words you mention are all hyphenated the way you suggest automatically. The default patterns are designed for natural language and don't work for camel case. You could put individual words in `\hyphenation` as you suggest or perhaps better mark them up as `\camel{SmartRoadSense}` where Camel allows breaking of camel case before each capital letter (There are answers for that, I'll find one)

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66593/automatic-camel-case-breaking/66603#66603

Comment: @egreg "incorrectly" is a very big word for me. But when I see in the output "anal-ysis" in my mind I think his hyphenation is "a-na-ly-sis". But, I repeat: I'm not native English.

Comment: You might like to check that you are actually loading the US English hyphenation tables...  can you post a compilable example, and your log file?

Comment: The default US patterns give `anal-y-sis` which looks about right (if slightly unfortunate) I don't think your breaks after either `a` are correct, tex never breaks after the first letter in english anyway

Comment: What egreg meant is what caused you to add monitoring to your hyphenation exception list? Do you have an example where it broke at a different point? If you do it indicates something else is wrong that you have not told us.

Comment: Ok. Thank you to all. I have understood that the problem is mine: I have to learn better English. This is not a LaTeX problem (except very long words or invented words).

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni US English hyphenation is much different from Italian (and from British English hyphenation either). Breaking after consonants is quite common.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TeX hyphenation is quite reliable, in general. However, some words can slip off its mechanism, because hyphenation is based on patterns. In order to be sure as much as possible of getting correct hyphenation in US English, load `ushyphex.tex`. See [Where can I find a list of English hyphenation exceptions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22867/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-english-hyphenation-exceptions)

If I try the simple document

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}%
  monitoring
  subsequently
  provisionally
  SmartRoadSense
}
\end{document}
```

so that words are split as much as possible, I get

[image]

If I add (in the preamble)

```
\input{ushyphex}
\hyphenation{Smart-Road-Sense}
```

I get

[image]

Note that “Sense” should not by hyphenated even if `\righthyphenmin` is less than its default value 3, because the final “e” is mute and so can't form a syllable center.

---

### Final word

Add `\input{ushyphex}` just to be very sure. Add explicit hyphenation only for “nonstandard words”.

Comment: Thank you also for `\hyphenation{Smart-Road-Sen-se}`.

Comment: as a native english speaker, i would *not* accept a hyphen before the `se` in `...Sense', even if `Sense` were followed by something else.  the fact that it isn't hyphenated in your test is simply owing to the setting `\righthyphenmin=3`.  (by contrast, i *would* accept a hyphen before `ly` in "subsequently" and "provisionally"; those are also not hyphenated here because of the `\righthyphenmin=3`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I just followed the OP on this, but I'll gladly fix the answer.

Comment: Setting `Smart-Road-Sen-se` is *definitely very incorrect*. It should be `Smart-Road-Sense`.