# Where can I find lists of non-US-English hyphenation exceptions?

Tags: babel, languages, hyphenation

As I learned from [Where can I find a list of English hyphenation exceptions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22867/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-english-hyphenation-exceptions), using the fine collection `ushyphex.tex` takes care of some of the known wrong  hyphenation for US-English. It also includes some proper names and internationalisms that will be useful for most languages.

Working with different (European) languages I noticed that also `babel`'s other hyphenation-patterns, including those for British English, have obvious shortcomings.

Are there collections like `ushyphex` out there and – if there aren't – wouldn't stackexchange be the right place to compile international exception lists  cooperatively?

Comment: No, there aren't and this site is not the right place for doing such kind of project.